# Uncaught TypeError: pre,template,textarea,script,style is not iterable

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, angular-cli

I am encountering this problem while my cordova app tries to run on my smartphone.

I'm using angular cli. I searched for the error specified and what I found was a closed issue on github where the solution (which worked for many) is to put the assets listed in .angular-cli.json in an array. The point is that my assets are already in an array. I've tried to look further but that issue is the only thing I've found.

However, compiling webpacks is successful and not by mistakes. The only mistake appears in the browser and is that of the title.

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This can be caused by lack of ES6 support. Can you try adding/uncommenting following in your Polyfill.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: I don't find any of the import statements in my polyfill.ts

Comment: this worked for me in an angular-cli project and saveed the day.  thanks @aix !

Comment: Thanks, uncommenting object, string and array was enough for me.

Comment: This solutions also resolves the error 
"Viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized and ignored"
when running ionic 4 app in android < 7