# White screen after splash screen in IONIC app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, apk, ionic3

I have a "problem" with my app. When it's running, after the splash screen and before the app is ready, a white screen appears for about 5/6 seconds and it's so annoying. 
How is it possible to avoid this white screen?

I didn't see a lot of questions about this (without working answers) and I would like to have an updated answer. I don't post code because I don't know which code could be useful.

Ionic version **3.13.2**

Thank you.

Comment: What does the console tells you ?

Comment: nothing. I use the apk on my mobile phone and I saw the white screen when I'm running on the device.

Comment: You may correct this with this solution. It worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834302/uncaught-typeerror-pre-template-textarea-script-style-is-not-iterable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be due to the fact that your application takes longer to load than the duration of the splahscreen.

In your config.xml file you may have something like:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

That means that the splashscreen will automatically fade out after 3 seconds. However, if your app is not ready after that time, you will see a white screen while your app finishes loading.

The solution is to set a longer time for your splashscreen and to also turn off `AutohideSplashScreen`. In the config.xml file:

```
<preference name="AutohideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
```

Then you need to make sure that you turn the splashscreen off from inside your app, as soon as your app is ready.

Typically in the `app.component.ts` class constructor:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Comment: @SHUBHASISMAHATA  This is incorrect, I created a new Ionic 5 / Cordova project and it still works the same.