# android ionic 4 white screen after splash screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework, screen, splash-screen

I have created a new the sample blank app in ionic 4 which works well in browser.

Then, I have added latest android platform to it and run it. It ended up with white screen after the splash screen. After I put my own welcome message in index.html, I could find that the app is never loaded. It shows the welcome message.

I have checked the APK with Bluestack and default android emulator. It does not work.

I checked all solutions that add tags to config.xml. I have also run this with--prod, --relese --livereload

But, no use. I have no idea with ionic and it is beta version either. Could you help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

With the app installed and running: in Chrome dev tools Three dots > Remote devices > Select your emulator > Inspect. Hit the refresh button and check the console for error messages. Usually the white screen is caused by a plugin not loading correctly. (The app-rate plugin especially seems to cause white screens).

Comment: Thanks for your quick support. I did accordingly and found the problem and have corrected with info from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834302/uncaught-typeerror-pre-template-textarea-script-style-is-not-iterable